# calling css from theme folder using xml layout

Tags: layout, css

i want to call css from theme folder using xml layout, below is code i am using:

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>design.css</stylesheet></action>
```

which calls css from below path:

```
http://URL-HERE/skin/frontend/base/default/design.css
```

but it call wrong css file i want to call it from current theme folder

like :

```
http://URL-HERE/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/css/design.css
```

How can i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/design.css</stylesheet></action>
```

You forgot to add "css" to stylesheet's path.